# change fragment on orientation change - Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 3 fragments, A, B and C that i have to display in a activity depending on the orientation of the screen.
In the portrait mode i want to display A and B, in the landscape mode i want to display B and C.

What is the best practice to add dynamically my fragments to the activity knowing that when the tablet is rotated, the activity calls the on Create method ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what these fragments are expected to do and other app related factors. In your case you can check display orientation in `onCreate()` or, if fragments are not added from code, create different layout file in `layout-land` with the same name and reference different fragments directly in XML

Comment: thanks,actually the fragments are added by code. How can my fragment B keep the same state (we suppose that he contains an EditText)?

another questions:
what is the use of layout-land and layout-port if i have to check my display orientation ?

should layout-land and layout-port be used only when you add your fragments directly in XML ?